# Resolving 'I found a duplicate for symbol...'

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

I'm trying to install System.Clipboard (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Clipboard-2.3.2.0) which has a dependency of Win32 >=2.2.0.0 && <2.4. I've successfully installed it but when trying to utilise the library im hit with the error message of duplicate symbol.

After reading about it I've learnt that only one of the libraries should be installed; namely, Win32-2.3.1.1 and Win32-2.6.1.0 are installed. If I remove 2.6.1.0, it will break multitudes of libraries (ghci, cabal, pretty much everything), but if I remove 2.3.1.1 I can't use the library.

I've also read about sandboxes, however if I install the library into a sandbox I can no longer import it into and use in my project.

My question is, is there any way I can specify that I want to utilise the 2.3.1.1 library? Or what can I do in this case?

Im on Windows

Comment: Using [stack](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/README/) is probably a good idea here. It acts a bit like a virtual environment like Python, but actually it does more since you also specify the "build plan", etc.

Comment: If you're building with cabal, you can specify package version in the .cabal file eg. see https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html section 3.1.4

Comment: The recommended ways of managing packages nowadays are either through Stack (see @WillemVanOnsem 's comment above) or through [cabal-install's set of `new-*` commands](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build-overview.html) (as opposed to the old commands like `cabal build`, which I guess you have been using up to now). Given that you are on Windows, Stack might be the easier option to set up.

Comment: As for your concrete problem, since Win32 is a core GHC library it cannot be easily replaced. That being so, you'll probably want to start using Stack (or, alternatively, remove the 2.3.1.1 version and start using the cabal-install `new-*` commands) and specify that you want to use 2.3.1.1 in your specific project only. Another possibility is doing what @ATayler alludes to: depending on your own version of `Clipboard` that accepts Win32-2.6 (both Stack and recent versions cabal-install have support for that).

Comment: I haven't reproduce your error but, recently, I have install Clipboard-2.3.2.0 using stack `lts-12.14` and It worked fine. Recall that this `lts` works with `ghc-8.4.3`. you might be using another version of `ghc`

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to update the library yourself to work with a newer version of `Win32` or to ask the author to do so for you.